# Dell integrated webcam does not work

Tags: drivers, webcam

I tried everything, googling dell integrated webcam... looked to answers. 
I deleted the driver, reinstalled it.

Nothing seems to work. Usually I find answers from google in forums , but this time no. IDK what to do. The webcam is not detected by the computer.

Thank you

Comment: Perhaps you could be more specific about "doesn't work"? Does it fail to appear in device manager at all, even as unknown hardware, does it not work in specific application - what?

Comment: It appears in the device manager, 
I update the driver but Windows keeps saying, the best driver is already installed...

Comment: So, the problem lies with a particular piece of software that is not recognizing it? What version of Windows are you running? It is entirely possible that Windows HAS installed the correct drivers if you're running Windows 7.

Comment: Windows 7.
No, the problem is ,I guess, windows not recognizing the webcam.
In device manager the webcam appears not installed, but I can't install it as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

Can you update either your chipset or video and audio drivers?

Comment: I did, no change.

Comment: And I assume it's had a reboot!? I would try to install another piece of software, as per Oliver G suggestion in the comments of your original post. Maybe Skype as that uses webcam?

Comment: Yes, reboot and yes skype.

I'll try reinstalling windows w/o formatting right now

Answer (score 0):

Once I saw the problem was not with the software rather with the cable.
The webcam driver was installed the icon would come up but the then once I would try to open it; it would say no webcam detected.

If you have experience then you should check the cable to see if it is burn out.

Comment: It's an integrated webcam. I can't open the monitor.

Comment: How new is the laptop? If under warranty, I'd send it back!

Comment: @Napster That is the reason why i said if you have experience opening laptops you should, or just go to a friend or a shop to where they can open it for free and then they'll show you the webcam cable. But it can definitely be opened on a laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. Seemed to be caused by Skype interfering with the drivers. I tried all the tricks of uninstalling the device and the faulty USB deveices etc.  But I discovered that it came back when after uninstalling all the related devices/USBs etc, I then used CCleaner to clean out my register. There were some strange items in there.\

After that - it worked!!
Try it.  Can't promise success, but won't hurt.

Comment: Anytime you doa regedit or clean it *CAN* hurt